WP Скрыть поле Description для кастомной таксономии
Есть созданная кастомная таксономия в WordPress
<?php
function create_works_category_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Works Categories',
        'singular_name'     => 'Works Category',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Works Categories',
        'all_items'         => 'All Works Categories',
        'parent_item'       => 'Parent Works Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Works Category:',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Works Category',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Works Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Works Category',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Works Category Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'Works Categories',
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'works-category' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'works-category', 'page', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_works_category_taxonomy' );

Вопрос - Есть ли какойто фильтр/хук который бы не отображал по умолчанию основное поле контента Description для данной таксономии ?

*Я понимаю что можно через CSS/JS но хотелось бы узнать может есть более чистое решение ?
Решение которое не сработало -
function remove_description_for_works_category($columns) {
    if (isset($_GET['taxonomy']) && $_GET['taxonomy'] === 'works-category') {
        unset($columns['description']);
    }
    return $columns;
}

add_filter('manage_edit-works-category_columns', 'remove_description_for_works_category');


Это фильтр для таблицы, где выводится список manage_{$screen->id}_columns

ok А есть что-то что может на входе отключить отображение ?

Я нашел только вариант с CSS
